# Plotly seems to lose labels of a heatmap

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to plot a heatmap of a 30x2322 weight matrix, with bias appended at the end with plotly. Here is the code:

```
def plotNetworkParams(fn, input_labels):
  np = loadFile(fn)
  input_mx = numpy.vstack([np[1], np[2]]) #stack bias to weight mx
  input_mx = numpy.transpose(input_mx)
  colorscale = [[0, '#000000'], [0.4, '#0000FF'], [0.5, '#FFFFFF'], [0.6, '#FFFF00'], [1, '#FF0000']]
  print "input mx shape: "+str(input_mx.shape) # prints (30, 2323)
  print "number of labels: "+str(len(input_labels)) # prints 2323
  data = [
            go.Heatmap(
                zauto=False,
                zmin=-0.5,
                zmax=0.5,
                colorscale = colorscale,
                z=input_mx,
                y=map(lambda n: "Activation of unit "+str(n), range(30)),
                x=input_labels
            )
          ]
  py.plot(data, filename="input_to_recurrent")
```

The plot has less labels on the x axis than columns. I traced it back to individual labels being missing using the offset between labels and data.
For example labels at index 275 and 277 are next to each other on the chart, label 276 is missing, and label 277 gets label 276's data and so on.

What can cause plotly to lose labels like this?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66313831/2166823

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I had inputs with the same label. Plotly has a "feature" to drop equal labels silently.

Comment: 5.5 years later and this "feature" just cost me my morning :)