# Plotly heatmap plot not rendering all yaxis labels

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-dash

I built an dash plotly dashboard with a heatmap. However I am noticing that t=some of the labels in my y-axis are not being shown. I am only getting a limited I am not sure what is going wrong. Here is my dashboard:

```
import dash
import dash_table
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input,Output
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
#correlation dataframe
correlation_df = supervisor[['Características (D)', 'Características (I)',
       'Características (S)', 'Características (C)', 'Motivación (D)',
       'Motivación (I)', 'Motivación (S)', 'Motivación (C)', 'Bajo Stress (D)',
       'Bajo Stress (I)', 'Bajo Stress (S)', 'Bajo Stress (C)','span','Mean Team Performance','employment span','Pay to team size ratio']]
correlation_df  = correlation_df.corr()
corr_fig = go.Figure()
corr_fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(
    z= correlation_df.values,
    x= ['Características (D)', 'Características (I)',
       'Características (S)', 'Características (C)', 'Motivación (D)',
       'Motivación (I)', 'Motivación (S)', 'Motivación (C)', 'Bajo Stress (D)',
       'Bajo Stress (I)', 'Bajo Stress (S)', 'Bajo Stress (C)','span','Mean Team Performance','employment span','Pay to team size ratio'],
    y= ['Características (D)', 'Características (I)',
       'Características (S)', 'Características (C)', 'Motivación (D)',
       'Motivación (I)', 'Motivación (S)', 'Motivación (C)', 'Bajo Stress (D)',
       'Bajo Stress (I)', 'Bajo Stress (S)', 'Bajo Stress (C)','span','Mean Team Performance','employment span','Pay to team size ratio'],
    hoverongaps=False
))
corr_fig.update_layout(title="Correlation heatmap",
                  yaxis={"title": 'Traits'},
                  xaxis={"title": 'Traits',"tickangle": 45}, )
app = dash.Dash()
#html layout
app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Dashboard', style={
        'textAlign': 'center',
        'height': '10'
    }),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='heatmap',
        figure=corr_fig.to_dict()
    )
    ])
if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Here is a sample of my dataframe:

```
{'Características (D)': {'Características (D)': 1.0,
  'Características (I)': -0.744432853713455,
  'Características (S)': 0.20085563028990697,
  'Características (C)': -0.039907357919985106,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.8232188768568326,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.6987940156295481,
  'Motivación (S)': 0.17336394623619988,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.03941838984936696,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.8142337605566142,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.48861318810993065,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.3207614659369065,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.0461134826855843,
  'span': 0.2874881163983965,
  'Mean Team Performance': 0.40633858242603244,
  'employment span': -0.09857697245687172,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.022958588188126107},
 'Características (I)': {'Características (D)': -0.744432853713455,
  'Características (I)': 1.0,
  'Características (S)': -0.3779100652350093,
  'Características (C)': -0.11879176229148546,
  'Motivación (D)': -0.8454566900924195,
  'Motivación (I)': 0.8314885901746485,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.5493813305976118,
  'Motivación (C)': 0.020902885445784,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': -0.4614762821424876,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 0.8628000011272827,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.07723803992022794,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.26492408476089707,
  'span': -0.2923189384010105,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.04150083345671622,
  'employment span': 0.4006484556146567,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.27081339758378836},
 'Características (S)': {'Características (D)': 0.20085563028990697,
  'Características (I)': -0.3779100652350093,
  'Características (S)': 1.0,
  'Características (C)': -0.7739057580439489,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.28928161764191546,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.14811042351159115,
  'Motivación (S)': 0.7823864767779756,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.6651182815949327,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.10162624205618695,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.5488737066087104,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.46905181352171205,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.4698328671560004,
  'span': -0.02087671997992093,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.12496266913575294,
  'employment span': 0.27001694775950746,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.07931062556531454},
 'Características (C)': {'Características (D)': -0.039907357919985106,
  'Características (I)': -0.11879176229148546,
  'Características (S)': -0.7739057580439489,
  'Características (C)': 1.0,
  'Motivación (D)': -0.011616389427962759,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.292733356844308,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.4343733032773228,
  'Motivación (C)': 0.774357808826908,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': -0.04367706074639601,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 0.0931714388059811,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': -0.6482541912883304,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': 0.7732581689662739,
  'span': 0.03775247426826095,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.07825282894287325,
  'employment span': -0.5003613024138532,
  'Pay to team size ratio': -0.20937248430293648},
 'Motivación (D)': {'Características (D)': 0.8232188768568326,
  'Características (I)': -0.8454566900924195,
  'Características (S)': 0.28928161764191546,
  'Características (C)': -0.011616389427962759,
  'Motivación (D)': 1.0,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.6401977926528387,
  'Motivación (S)': 0.27806883694592277,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.2534345146499511,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.35748019323906,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.7219032007713697,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.21293087519106632,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': 0.2698254124168881,
  'span': 0.5037240436882805,
  'Mean Team Performance': 0.48414442720369955,
  'employment span': -0.20711331594020507,
  'Pay to team size ratio': -0.3769998767635495},
 'Motivación (I)': {'Características (D)': -0.6987940156295481,
  'Características (I)': 0.8314885901746485,
  'Características (S)': -0.14811042351159115,
  'Características (C)': -0.292733356844308,
  'Motivación (D)': -0.6401977926528387,
  'Motivación (I)': 1.0,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.48288361435623983,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.4135335004412625,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': -0.5563645790627242,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 0.45272622386580263,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.31345796324782077,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.1236088717264958,
  'span': -0.4334332491868192,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.027223644357210867,
  'employment span': 0.08277408562811393,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.30770777808996924},
 'Motivación (S)': {'Características (D)': 0.17336394623619988,
  'Características (I)': -0.5493813305976118,
  'Características (S)': 0.7823864767779756,
  'Características (C)': -0.4343733032773228,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.27806883694592277,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.48288361435623983,
  'Motivación (S)': 1.0,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.23220036735524985,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.12079023858043715,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.5418626995091027,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': -0.12381340765657087,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.3091698232697242,
  'span': 0.1503231802207429,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.38838798587565976,
  'employment span': 0.09981399691805137,
  'Pay to team size ratio': -0.20858825983296703},
 'Motivación (C)': {'Características (D)': -0.03941838984936696,
  'Características (I)': 0.020902885445784,
  'Características (S)': -0.6651182815949327,
  'Características (C)': 0.774357808826908,
  'Motivación (D)': -0.2534345146499511,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.4135335004412625,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.23220036735524985,
  'Motivación (C)': 1.0,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.18028688548066718,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 0.386437402512207,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': -0.7351725371592022,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': 0.21452556505271267,
  'span': 0.15796613914842977,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.11411844367303944,
  'employment span': -0.1335403092401566,
  'Pay to team size ratio': -0.16110863218572585},
 'Bajo Stress (D)': {'Características (D)': 0.8142337605566142,
  'Características (I)': -0.4614762821424876,
  'Características (S)': 0.10162624205618695,
  'Características (C)': -0.04367706074639601,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.35748019323906,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.5563645790627242,
  'Motivación (S)': 0.12079023858043715,
  'Motivación (C)': 0.18028688548066718,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 1.0,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.1849352428080063,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.2529157606770202,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.31055770095686547,
  'span': -0.11631187918782246,
  'Mean Team Performance': 0.05369401779765192,
  'employment span': -0.042901905999867325,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.4484652828139771},
 'Bajo Stress (I)': {'Características (D)': -0.48861318810993065,
  'Características (I)': 0.8628000011272827,
  'Características (S)': -0.5488737066087104,
  'Características (C)': 0.0931714388059811,
  'Motivación (D)': -0.7219032007713697,
  'Motivación (I)': 0.45272622386580263,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.5418626995091027,
  'Motivación (C)': 0.386437402512207,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': -0.1849352428080063,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 1.0,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': -0.0981237735359993,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.27961420029017486,
  'span': -0.06711566955045667,
  'Mean Team Performance': 0.06327392392569486,
  'employment span': 0.5471491483201977,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.17612214868518486},
 'Bajo Stress (S)': {'Características (D)': 0.3207614659369065,
  'Características (I)': 0.07723803992022794,
  'Características (S)': 0.46905181352171205,
  'Características (C)': -0.6482541912883304,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.21293087519106632,
  'Motivación (I)': 0.31345796324782077,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.12381340765657087,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.7351725371592022,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.2529157606770202,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.0981237735359993,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 1.0,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.3570697743190169,
  'span': -0.23885238917830093,
  'Mean Team Performance': 0.41404235485716345,
  'employment span': 0.33146618322475935,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.49978958145813196},
 'Bajo Stress (C)': {'Características (D)': -0.0461134826855843,
  'Características (I)': -0.26492408476089707,
  'Características (S)': -0.4698328671560004,
  'Características (C)': 0.7732581689662739,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.2698254124168881,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.1236088717264958,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.3091698232697242,
  'Motivación (C)': 0.21452556505271267,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': -0.31055770095686547,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.27961420029017486,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': -0.3570697743190169,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': 1.0,
  'span': -0.01344626398272969,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.08070306908833835,
  'employment span': -0.5968535698213163,
  'Pay to team size ratio': -0.2795657757692292},
 'span': {'Características (D)': 0.2874881163983965,
  'Características (I)': -0.2923189384010105,
  'Características (S)': -0.02087671997992093,
  'Características (C)': 0.03775247426826095,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.5037240436882805,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.4334332491868192,
  'Motivación (S)': 0.1503231802207429,
  'Motivación (C)': 0.15796613914842977,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': -0.11631187918782246,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': -0.06711566955045667,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': -0.23885238917830093,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.01344626398272969,
  'span': 1.0,
  'Mean Team Performance': -0.19851531030268585,
  'employment span': 0.13994502995917002,
  'Pay to team size ratio': -0.802380461421258},
 'Mean Team Performance': {'Características (D)': 0.40633858242603244,
  'Características (I)': -0.04150083345671622,
  'Características (S)': -0.12496266913575294,
  'Características (C)': -0.07825282894287325,
  'Motivación (D)': 0.48414442720369955,
  'Motivación (I)': -0.027223644357210867,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.38838798587565976,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.11411844367303944,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.05369401779765192,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 0.06327392392569486,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.41404235485716345,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.08070306908833835,
  'span': -0.19851531030268585,
  'Mean Team Performance': 1.0,
  'employment span': 0.3992240651662481,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.38910257451919805},
 'employment span': {'Características (D)': -0.09857697245687172,
  'Características (I)': 0.4006484556146567,
  'Características (S)': 0.27001694775950746,
  'Características (C)': -0.5003613024138532,
  'Motivación (D)': -0.20711331594020507,
  'Motivación (I)': 0.08277408562811393,
  'Motivación (S)': 0.09981399691805137,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.1335403092401566,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': -0.042901905999867325,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 0.5471491483201977,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.33146618322475935,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.5968535698213163,
  'span': 0.13994502995917002,
  'Mean Team Performance': 0.3992240651662481,
  'employment span': 1.0,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 0.04572394154746432},
 'Pay to team size ratio': {'Características (D)': 0.022958588188126107,
  'Características (I)': 0.27081339758378836,
  'Características (S)': 0.07931062556531454,
  'Características (C)': -0.20937248430293648,
  'Motivación (D)': -0.3769998767635495,
  'Motivación (I)': 0.30770777808996924,
  'Motivación (S)': -0.20858825983296703,
  'Motivación (C)': -0.16110863218572585,
  'Bajo Stress (D)': 0.4484652828139771,
  'Bajo Stress (I)': 0.17612214868518486,
  'Bajo Stress (S)': 0.49978958145813196,
  'Bajo Stress (C)': -0.2795657757692292,
  'span': -0.802380461421258,
  'Mean Team Performance': 0.38910257451919805,
  'employment span': 0.04572394154746432,
  'Pay to team size ratio': 1.0}}
```

This is a snap shot of what the heatmap looks like if you run my code:
[image: Plot Image]

Comment: You could shrink your example as `dash` is not needed here.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `yaxis_nticks` property of the layout to specify the number of ticks you want to show.

For example, you can have as many ticks as you have rows in your dataframe.

```py
corr_fig.update_layout(title="Correlation heatmap",
                  yaxis={"title": 'Traits'},
                  xaxis={"title": 'Traits',"tickangle": 45},
                  yaxis_nticks=len(supervisor))
```

which renders as
[image]

Answer (score 2):

So I was able to resolve this issue by increasing the length of my heatmap. I am assuming some of the y labels were being cut off because of the size of my heatmap

```
corr_fig.update_layout(title="Correlation heatmap",
                  yaxis={"title": 'Traits'},
                  width=1200,
                  height=1400,
                  xaxis={"title": 'Traits',"tickangle": 45}, )
```

Comment: it's actually weird the plot is generated on a fixed scale independent of the y labels

Answer (score 0):

I was able to display all of my y-axis labels of the heatmap by applying

```
yaxis: {
    autotick: false
}
```

with `plotly.js`.