# Ploty heatmap plot ony 50 y coordinates

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I have such a dataframe and would like to draw a heatmap, example of the data:

```
ID       Year       A          B        C
ID1      1971       5          100      0.5
ID1      1972       6          102      0.4
ID1      1981       4          101      0.6
ID1      1991       5          103      0.5
ID1      1993       2          104      0.4
ID2      1971       4          100      0.9
ID2      1973       4          108      0.8
ID2      1981       5          109      0.7
ID2      1991       3          106      0.6
ID2      1993       3          103      0.5
```

I am trying to plot a heatmap with ploty but the plot show only 50 y-coordinates. My data contain about 10.000 unique IDs:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
fig = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
    z=df['B'],
    x=df['Year'],
    y=df['ID'],
    colorscale='Viridis'))
fig.write_html("test.html")
```

How to plot the entire dataset?

Comment: A heat map has 3 axis, two regular x, y and the colour let's call it z, what do you want to plot on x and y, what do you want to plot on z (raw data, aggregate)?

Answer (score 0):

For heatmap, z should be a two-dimension array, but you only give a series which is one-dimensional, so there may be some mismatch. May be you can do some reshape before plotting, like create a matrix with the right size and update the value of each element according to your dataset. Look out for missing value though. Need some manual work here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

- have taken your sample data and bulked it up to 1000 IDs
- all 1000 are plotting, it's just the axes is a sample (take a look at hover info)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import io
import numpy as np

# df = pd.read_csv("my_data.csv")
df = pd.read_csv(
    io.StringIO(
        """ID       Year       A          B        C
ID1      1971       5          100      0.5
ID1      1972       6          102      0.4
ID1      1981       4          101      0.6
ID1      1991       5          103      0.5
ID1      1993       2          104      0.4
ID2      1971       4          100      0.9
ID2      1973       4          108      0.8
ID2      1981       5          109      0.7
ID2      1991       3          106      0.6
ID2      1993       3          103      0.5"""
    ),
    sep="\s+",
)

# bulk up sample data to 1000 IDs
df = pd.concat(
    [
        df.assign(
            ID=np.repeat([f"ID{i+1}", "ID{i+2}"], len(df) // 2),
            B=np.random.randint(df["B"].min(), df["B"].max(), len(df)),
        )
        for i in range(1000)
    ]
)

fig = go.Figure(
    data=go.Heatmap(z=df["B"], x=df["Year"], y=df["ID"], colorscale="Viridis")
)

fig
```

[image]

Comment: This is somehow a meaningless representation for a heatmap and it is pretty unreadable. But without having more precision from the OP it would be difficult to do better.

Answer (score 0):

With increasing the size of the heatmap, all IDs are now displayed:

[Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60194913/221270)

```
fig.update_layout(title="Correlation heatmap",
              yaxis={"title": 'Test'},

              height=10000,
              xaxis={"title": 'Test',"tickangle": 13000} )
```